# tar.gz alternative for archiving with ability to quickly display the archives contents

Tags: linux, gzip, command-line-interface, tar

Usually I create archives of data in linux at the commandline with tar & gzip (or [pigz](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/) - as this uses parallel processing for compression).

However, listing the contents of such an archive is painfully slow because of the sequential format of tar archives. This is especially true if an archive contains many files that are several GB each.

What is an alternative to my combination to create gzipped tar archives of files in linux. Especially I'm looking for something that allows for a retrieval of the list or tree of files inside the archives, similar to tar - but much more performant?

Answer (score 4):

[zip](http://info-zip.org/)? The zip file format contains a catalog of the contents (at the end, IIRC), which can be retrieved with zipinfo(1).

Comment: Yes but OP is talking about tar.gz... the tar is zipped so the zip catalog will contain only one file...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: I meant zip, as in the pkzip format rather than gzip/deflate. I added a link to info-zip (the usual unix implementation) which hopefully clarifies my answer.

Comment: Maybe an alternative for some - but keep in mind that zip does not save the chmod structure and the file size limit is 4GB.

Comment: @ChristianHerenz: Info-zip which I linked to which is the usual zip implementation on unix platforms, does save the file attribute flags. Also, it supports the "ZIP64" extensions, which AFAIU means it can handle large files. That being said, while it saves the file attribute flags and modification time, it seems it doesn't save the ctime or atime. So it depends what you want, if that is a showstopper.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[7zip](https://7-zip.org/7z.html) is probably the best solution nowadays.

ZIP format is a bit outdated and was designed for FAT filesystem, which is where many of its limitations come from.

[dar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dar/) also might be an option. But as far as I can tell there is only one developer and no community around (unlike 7zip which has several forks and ports made by independent developers).